# MongoDB - update referenced field

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have a queried document, which I populated from other documents. My question is whether it is possible to update the referenced document or do I have to create new query for the other document using the id fields.

Example (code in mongoosejs):

```
Users.findById(id).populate('library.id', null, 'BookModel').exec(function(err, user) 
    user.library.id.loc.coordinates = [40, 20];
    user.save();
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in the docs for [`populate`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html):

> The documents returned from query population become fully functional,
>   removeable, saveable documents unless the lean option is specified. Do
>   not confuse them with sub docs. Take caution when calling its remove
>   method because you'll be removing it from the database, not just the
>   array.

So yes, you can modify the referenced, populated documents directly and call `save` on them to commit any changes.  But you need to call `save` on the referenced document to do it:

```js
Users.findById(id).populate('library.id', null, 'BookModel').exec(function(err, user) 
    user.library.id.loc.coordinates = [40, 20];
    user.library.id.save();
});
```

Comment: I searched everywhere but for some reason I didn't stumble upon that paragraph. And still I wouldn't know how to save. Thanks a lot :)